# error in metaTag disctription not displaying

Tags: wordpress, seo, meta

error in metaTag disctription not displaying google search engine display's diffrent information which is not in my site.

site:[discoverindiantours.com](http://discoverindiantours.com)

above url is a wordpress site i have used wordpress plugin for search engine optimization

while writing above statement in Google search engine
i am not getting expected metatag description below the link in search engine.
need to know the reason if anybody could help.

Answer (score 1):

The meta description values are merely a hint for search engines. If they're low quality or repeated across the whole site, it's very likely Google and other search engines will not make use of them.

Try to have unique, high quality meta descriptions; that increases the chance they are going to be used, although still not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Google can pick any content from your web page, whether it is your meta description or content of your page. It depends on the query, which you are searching.